# openni_camera slow publish rate - how to configure?

Tags: kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening,

I'm aware of a previous claim similar to this one, but with a multi-post:
[answers::frame-rate-low-and-depth-wrong](http://answers.ros.org/question/227/frame-rate-low-and-depth-wrong).
I'd like to make a single claim since my depth values are alright, but the frame rate is low. I would like to know whether this is expected behavior, or I haven't configured something correctly, e.g. the publish rate.

I followed instructions on the page [wiki::openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera). Here are the details.

`[/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera]$ hg tip<br/>
changeset:   255:790164436991<br/>
tag:         tip<br/>
user:        Tully Foote [email removed]<br/>
date:        Mon Mar 07 19:23:19 2011 -0800<br/>
summary:     releasing 0.1.2  **&larr;&larr;&larr;&larr; openni_kinect stack version** <br/>
<br/>
$ rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_mono 
average rate: 7.881 **←←←← not close to 30hz for VGA mode**

        min: 0.032s max: 0.968s std dev: 0.12043s window: 202 


$ rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points

average rate: 1.663 **←←←← less than 2hz after 1200 samples**

        min: 0.017s max: 4.500s std dev: 0.55721s window: 1200`

My configuration is: x86_64 GNU/Linux (ubuntu SMP), and I'm running the core and node on the same machine (single launch file).

I looked into `OpenNINodelet`, but it was difficult to figure out the rate since (i) `imageCallback()` is registered though the OpenNI driver, and, (ii) I'm inexperienced beyond this (I have not tried any other OpenNI-based drivers).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Nikhil

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10168/openni_camera-slow-publish-rate---how-to-configure?/) by [scribbleink](https://answers.ros.org/users/647/scribbleink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue was that I plugged the Kinect into a laptop eSATA/USB 2-in-1 port, which dropped the frame rates, for some reason that I'm not willing to investigate further.

On the normal USB port on the same laptop, I get ~30hz for the images and ~22hz for the RGB PCL points.

Sorry for the trouble, I should have checked this before posting.

---

Originally posted by [scribbleink](https://answers.ros.org/users/647/scribbleink/) with karma: 116 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1